# Can't create new table in Mysql used foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-workbench

This is what i have used to create new table

```
CREATE TABLE history(  
search_id int auto_increment=1000 primary key,  
f_name varchar(100) not null,  
f_lo varchar(300) not null,  
u_id varchar(50) not null unique,  
foreign key(u_id) references userinfo(user_id)  
);
```

This is the error I'm facing

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near '=1000 primary key,   f_name varchar(100) not null,
> f_lo varchar(300) not null,   u_i' at line 2

Refer this image :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXeoO.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE history(
search_id int auto_increment primary key,
f_name varchar(100) not null,
f_lo varchar(300) not null,
u_id varchar(50) not null unique,
foreign key(u_id) references userinfo(user_id)
);
```

**Try not to initialize auto increment**

Once you create the above table you can alter it by:

```
ALTER TABLE history AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

[`link to refer`](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/auto_increment.php#:%7E:text=In%20MySQL%2C%20the%20syntax%20to,value%20you%20wish%20to%20change.)

Answer (score 0):

AUTO_INCREMENT value is table option, not column option or default value. See [CREATE TABLE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html).

So

```sql
CREATE TABLE history(
    search_id int auto_increment primary key,
    f_name varchar(100) not null,
    f_lo varchar(300) not null,
    u_id varchar(50) not null unique,
    foreign key(u_id) references userinfo(user_id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```